# Receiving error when trying to select object and add click event with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Keep getting the error

```
 "--
[18:37:08.353] Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead. @ chrome://firebug/content/chrome/tabContext.js:589"
```

and

```
"[18:37:10.710] TypeError: myNode is null @ http://site.com/image:89"
```

Im using Ruby on Rails, webBrick, and FireFox..

Set this up to see if I could get anything to show in the console on clicking... Received errors above instead..

```
<script>

(function() {
    var myNode = document.querySelector('#img-list ul.grid');

    myNode.addEventListener("click", function(e) { 
        console.log(e);
    }, false);

})();

</script>

<style>

li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
    height:auto;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;   
}

#img-list {
    width:330px;
}

</style>


<div id="img-list">
    <ul class="grid">
        <li><img src="assets/1/1_1.png"></li>
        <li><img src="assets/1/1_2.png"></li>
        <li><img src="assets/1/1_3.png"></li>
        <li><img src="assets/1/1_4.png"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<script>` is executed when the browser sees it and that happens before `#img-list` is in the DOM so `document.querySelector('#img-list ul.grid')` doesn't find anything.

Since your question is tagged with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), why don't you use it?

```
$(function() {
    $('#img-list ul.grid').click(function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
});
```

That will delay running your JavaScript until after the DOM is ready.